# Ant Ivy retrieve Task: What are the valid values for attribute type?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

The documentation here http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/retrieve.html is unclear.

"comma separated list of accepted artifact types (since 1.4)"

Examples I have seen:

1. `<ivy:retrieve pattern="${libs.dir}/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]" />`

   - Does this mean all artifact types?
   - I have seen a type **bundle** get downloaded for Google Guava.
2. `<ivy:retrieve type="jar" pattern="${libs.dir}/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]" />`
3. `<ivy:retrieve type="source" pattern="${libs.dir}/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]" />`

Answer (score 1):

The `type` attribute corresponds to the type of the dependency's artifact declared in `publications` section of a dependency descriptor ([`ivy.xml` file](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ivyfile/artifact.html)). In your own dependencies, you can generally use any value of type in accordance with your logical considerations. For runnable jars you use `jar` type, for packed sources `source`, for packed docs `docs` etc. Conceptually it's close to artifact file extension.

```
<publications>
   <artifact name="${module.artifact.jar.name}" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master" />
   <artifact name="${module.artifact.src.name}" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" />
</publications>
```

When you depend on a third party library, the value of `type` will correspondingly equal to what is declared in its ivy.xml (or will be defined by the way how ivy.xml is automatically converted from maven pom.xml if using a maven repo). I guess an artifact of the `bundle` type is ready to be used in osgi environment (not sure about it).

I would say that normally you don't have to specify `type` in `retrieve` task. Instead you specify configuration `conf` (like scope in maven), and the configuration will bring those types that are mapped to it in `publications->artifact` section of `ivy.xml`. E.g., when you retrieve the `master` conf, an artifact of `jar` type is retrieved; when you ask retrieve for `sources` conf, an artifact of type `source` comes.